# PHP функция preg_match обрезает текст

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Из формы приходит текст вида

```
[reply-to=16]
reply to comment
another text
```

Пытаюсь его обработать функцией PHP preg_match, но по непонятной для меня причине в карманы попадает лишь последняя строка текста. Т.е. код:

```
$text = <<<EOL
[reply-to=16]
reply to comment
another text
EOL;
preg_match("#\s?(\[reply\-to=(\d+)\])?(.*)$#iu", $text, $poc);
print_r($poc);
```

выдаёт:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
another text
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => another text
)
```

Хотя в $poc[0] я ожидаю увидеть весь текст, а в $poc[3] весь текст без [reply-to=16]

В чём ошибка и как её исправить?

Comment: [s (PCRE_DOTALL)
Если данный модификатор используется, метасимвол "точка" в шаблоне соответствует всем символам, включая перевод строк. Без него - все символы, кроме переводов строк.](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: `s` добавьте в модификаторы